# Where sqlerrm variable error message are stored in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am try to store error log of the stored procedure in customize error table using exception block and sqleerm in-built variable of redshift

```
 DECLARE
     name emp.ename%TYPE;
     v_code NUMBER;
     v_errm VARCHAR2(64);
     BEGIN
    SELECT ename INTO name FROM emp WHERE empno = 1000;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    v_code := SQLCODE;
    v_errm := SUBSTR(sqlerrm, 1 , 64);
    INSERT INTO emp_exceptions
      (err_code,err_msg
      ) VALUES
      (v_code,v_errm
      );
      COMMIT;
      END;`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do much with exception handling in Redshift. The docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-trapping-errors.html say that

> The only supported condition is [`EXCEPTION WHEN`] `OTHERS`, which matches every error type except query cancellation.

and

> [...] the only supported *handler_statement* is `RAISE`.

My reading of it, and extensive failed experimentation, is that your ambitious Oracle styled exception handling block can't be written in Redshift.